# Getting control over positioning of v-for items

Tags: javascript, postgresql, vue.js, v-for

Im working on a information-management system (vuejs, postgresql, graphql/hasura) for my company at the moment. We work project-based and have a lot of information to handle. Using postgresql, I've set up a few tables, ex client_information, general_information, internal_information and so on. (see structure below)

```
title -----| value | completed | date | project_number
-------------------------------------------------
customer -- walmart -- true ----- xx ----- 19823 --
contact --- xxxxxx --- false ---- xx ----- 19823 --
email ----- xxxxxx --- false ---- xx ----- 19823 --
```

So, this table with client_info contains info about all the clients we have, and each row is connected to a project by it's project number (19823). So, using hasura(graphQL) I make a request that returns all information about a chosen project in the form of a array filled with objects:

```
[ { title: 'customer', value: 'walmart', completed: true, 
date: 'xx' project_number: 10823 }, {...}, {...}, {...} ]
```

So far all is fine and dandy, I could just v-for through the entire array and spit out all the information I need.
BUT, I'd like to be able to control in which order the items are displayed. During testing I created a function that takes in the array of objects above, and an array that I specify on the client looking like this:

```
['email', 'customer', 'contact']
```

This orders the array of items in the order specified, and works, but feels.. weird?

Consider this example:

This is my array:

```
const arr = [
    {title: "customer", value: "walmart"},
    {title: "email", value: "xx@xx.xx"},
    {title: "phone", value: "01234"}
];
```

Then I do a:

```
<li v-for="item in arr">, text-field(vuetify) with placeholder="item.title", and v-model="item.value" </li>
```

That prints out the 3 items in the order of the array, so customer first, then email, then phone. What I don't understand is how to arrange the order of items. Maybe I want phone first, with a v-for loop, how is that possible? And yes, the array is way longer than just 3 items.

It might be that it's my first time using a relational database and my lack of experience is messing me up, but with the old database (firebase) everything was quite easy since each project was stored as a separate object. If I wanted the client email I'd just link a text-field to project.customer.email, and therefore had control. For reasons we need to move to postgresql and I'm not sure how to get the same control, maybe my solution is an "okay" one even though it feels a little weird to me, I dont know.

I was thinking about indexing the items in the db but I'd like to control if from the client in case we need to make layout-changes later on.
This turned into a novel, but if any of you guys have faced a similar situation and have some tips I'd greatly appreciate them.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to present the items?  I don't understand why you aren't using `v-for` no matter what and then changing how the data is presented in the view layer.  Particularly, I don't understand the need for a second array dictating property order.

Comment: So, you mean to create a specific view in the DB where everything is in the correct order? Then just query the view? Does work I guess, but a colleage told me earlier that the client should be in control of the layout, and the database should not be. Thats why I have not considered that as an option :/ Code is a simple v-for loop of the array of objects, nothing fancy.

Comment: No, when I say view layer, I mean the client side HTML.  Your colleague is correct about where the layout should be handled.  That's why I'm confused about the problem at hand.  I think I may not be understanding what data you have or how it is given to you that's why I'm asking you to add the code that would help reproduce the issue.

Comment: If its a small list, doing it on the client side is okay I believe. You could use a computed property which returns a sorted list of objects and then use it in the v-for In case of huge lists, processing it on the back-end would be ideal.

Comment: @zero298 Okay, lets simplify. This is my array: 
const arr = [ {title: "customer", value: "walmart" } {title: "email", value: "xx@xx.xx"} {title: "phone", value: "01234"} ];
Then I do a <li v-for="item in arr">, text-field(vuetify) with placeholder="item.title", and v-model="item.value" </li> 

That prints out the 3 items in the order of the array, so customer first, then email, then phone. 
What I don't understand is how to arrange the order of items. Maybe I want phone first, with a v-for loop, how is that possible?
And yes, the array is waaay longer than just 3items.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  If you are just receiving all the "properties" in a big array as you show, then I think your approach of transforming the given piece with an array of how you need these elements to be ordered is valid.

Comment: Use a pre-made table widget.  There are scores of them, and they all have a `columns` property that does what you ask.. Why reinvent the wheel?